# How to add multiple columns of different lengths to DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have to build my DataFrame column-by-column in a loop. Each column has different lengths.

I start with an empty DataFrame, but I know the column names already:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['g1','g2'])
```

My column data are extracted from another DataFrame as Series. Let's create some fictitious ones here:

```
s1 = pd.Series(index=[1,2],data=[10,11],name='g1')
s2 = pd.Series(index=[3,4,5],data=[12,13,14],name='g2')
# etc.
```

Note that the two series have different index values AND different lengths (not all index values are different, some may overlap).
Now I want to go into the loop and add a new column to my DataFrame at each iteration. At the and of the loop, my DataFrame should look like this:

```
Index      g1      g2
0          10      12
1          11      13
2          NaN     14
```

In other words:

1. The index is expanded to cover the largest column AND reset to 0..n-1, where n is the max. length of all the columns
2. Each series is appended as a new column, with the same name as the original known column names
3. Missing elements are NaN

Answer (score 3):

With [`name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.name.html) and [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({s.name: s.reset_index(drop=True) for s in [s1, s2]})
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

     g1  g2
0  10.0  12
1  11.0  13
2   NaN  14
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. You misunderstood my question. I do not have all of the columns when I create the DataFrame. What is was asking for is a way to add columns one at a time, starting with an empty DataFrame. It is true that building the list of series in my loop, then constructing the DataFrame at the end may be the easiest way to solve this.

Comment: You're welcome and sorry, I don't get you! Can you be more specific ? We agree that you have a list of series predefined ? Have you tried to run the code ? `pd.DataFrame` they call it the constructor for a reason. Anyways, if it does not answer your question, you probably missed a detail when describing your issue.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I do have a list of all of my column names, but I don't have the data for each column at the beginning. I get the data for each column at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: What do you get after adding my piece of code to yours then run it ? Actually, you don't even need to initialize an empty dataframe with `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['g1','g2'])`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and parameter `drop=True` for default index:

```
L = [s1, s2]

df = pd.concat([s.reset_index(drop=True) for s in L], axis=1)
print (df)
     g1  g2
0  10.0  12
1  11.0  13
2   NaN  14
```

Loop solution:

```
L = [s1, s2]

for s in L:
    s1 = s.reset_index(drop=True)
    df = df.reindex(s1.index)
    df[s1.name] = s1
print (df)
     g1  g2
0  10.0  12
1  11.0  13
2   NaN  14
```

Comment: your code will not work in the case the last column has fewer data than the previous ones. Example: `s3 = pd.Series(index=[7],data=[15],name='g3')`. However, using `concat` looks promising. I will post a solution below if I find one.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer of [@Timeless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75936226/16343464), if you want to update the original DataFrame in place, you can use:

```
l = [s1, s2]

tmp = pd.DataFrame({s.name: s.reset_index(drop=True) for s in l})

df[list(tmp)] = tmp

print(df)
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
df[list(tmp)] = (tmp:=pd.DataFrame({s.name: s.reset_index(drop=True) for s in [s1, s2]}))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
     g1  g2
0  10.0  12
1  11.0  13
2   NaN  14
```

Comment: I hope you're doing good, your solution is more flexible than mine +1. Btw, I made a small update to the github repo last week if you can take a look ;)

Comment: @Timeless I'm doing good thanks. Looks nice, I like a lot the detailed description of the answer(s), that will be a lot of work though. Thanks again for that ;)

Comment: @Timeless and congrats you had a lot of nice answers today

Comment: Thanks mozway, I appreciate it! Coming from you, that means a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two solutions I found:

1. Thanks to @Timeless. The first solution builds a list of series in the loop, then a DataFrame is constructed using a dict at the end.

```
    series_list = []
    for i in col_names:
        series_list.append(series)
    df = pd.DataFrame({s.name: s.reset_index(drop=True) for s in series_list})
```

2. Thanks to `jezrael`, who had the insight of using `concat` instead of `merge`, which I was trying to use at first. In this case, we start with an empty DataFrame, then add a new column at each iteration. We reset the index of the series before adding it. The advantage of using `concat` instead of just assigning the series to a column, is that `concat` automatically enlarges the DataFrame as needed

```
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    s = # get new column at each iteration
    for i in col_names:
        df = pd.concat([df,s.reset_index(drop=True).rename(i)],axis=1)
```